# How to mention a professor that his CV link in the university website do not work?

Tags: graduate-admissions, communication

I want to e-mail to a professor in a US university to get a PhD position. The links of *CV download* and *personal homepage* for all the professors in the specific faculty do not work.
How can I mention this fact in my email?
Actually, I want to mention this to make the professor aware of the fact that I have checked his page and not chosen him by chance!

Answer (score 5):

First, check you are on the correct (current) website. It may be that the university/department changed their websites and you landed on an old version, which is not updated or already partly removed.

If you are sure you are on the correct page, and it is the case for *all* professors (and faculty) that links are not working [as you write], contact the webmaster rather than the professor. There will be a more general problem that is not to be solved by the professors themselves.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I want to mention this to make the professor aware of the fact that I have checked his page and not chosen him by chance!

Comment: There is a better ways to do this: describe why you want to work with _him/her_, for example how your research interests match.

Comment: @Mark: That's the reason he found the problem in the first place. It's also hard to write if there are broken links that prevent you from finding the information you want.

Comment: @aeismail what is your suggestion?